# How to fix 'ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [32979, 21602]'?

Tags: machine-learning, text, scikit-learn, nlp, train-test-split

I am making a Logistic Regression model to do sentiment analysis. This is the problem - `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [32979, 21602]`
This occurs when I try to split my dataset into x and y train and valid sets.

```
# splitting data into training and validation set 
xtrain_bow, xvalid_bow, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(train_bow, train['label'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
lreg = LogisticRegression() # training the model 
lreg.fit(xtrain_bow, ytrain) 
prediction = lreg.predict_proba(xvalid_bow) # predicting on the validation set 
prediction_int = prediction[:,1] >= 0.3 # if prediction is greater than or equal to 0.3 than 1 else 0 
prediction_int = prediction_int.astype(np.int) 
f1_score(yvalid, prediction_int) # calculating f1 score for the validation set
```

I saw in some posts that it can occur because of the shape of the X and y, so printed out the shapes of the datset, I have splitted my dataset into 85% for training and rest for test/valid purpose.

```
# Extracting train and test BoW features
split_frac = 0.85

split_num = int(len(combi['tidy_tweet']) * split_frac)

train_bow = bow[:split_num,:] 
test_bow = bow[split_num:,:] 
print(train_bow.shape)
print(test_bow.shape)
print(train['label'].shape)

(32979, 1000)
(5820, 1000)
(21602,)
```

Also the problem is in this line-

```
----> 1 xtrain_bow, xvalid_bow, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(train_bow, train['label'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
      2 lreg = LogisticRegression() # training the model
      3 lreg.fit(xtrain_bow, ytrain)
```

Now I am clueless, that what is actually causing the problem? Can you guys please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting above error because the length of second parameter, i.e., the label, in `train_test_split()` is `21602` while the length of first parameter is `32979`, which should not be. The length both X and Y data must be same. So, check the length of `train_bow` and `train['label']`.

So, just change

`xtrain_bow, xvalid_bow, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(train_bow, train['label'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)` 
to something like below:

```
xtrain_bow, xvalid_bow, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(bow[:split_num,:-1], bow[:split_num,-1], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

(Assuming `bow` contains both features and labels, labels being the last column).

Read more `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Comment: Thanks, but bow does not contain labels, bow only contain tidy preprocessed tweets, `bow = bow_vectorizer.fit_transform(combi['tidy_tweet']) `. labels are taken from train variable, which is the actual csv file. So, do I need to change my `y` from `bow[:split_num,-1]` to `train['label']` or anything else?

Comment: Okay. But, you get the idea what I want to say?

Comment: You have to pass label of equal length as the first parameter, i.e., X.

Comment: Above example is just an example.

Comment: Okay, means labels of size (32979, ) instead of (21602,)? Is it?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is really informative, but one last question, should I reshape my train['label'] to (32979, ) to make it (32979, )?

Comment: (32979, ) and (32979, ) are same. Just passed it.

Comment: no no, I am asking train['label'] is (21602, ), so I should reshape it, right? to make it (32979, ), right?

Comment: then? how can I change the shape?

Comment: Or you can do one thing just change `train_bow = bow[:split_num,:]` to `train_bow = bow[:len(train['label']),:]`

Comment: Well, can you please elaborate, I am pretty new in this field, especially about sci-kit learn. in the second part, `train_bow` or `xvalid_bow`?

Comment: Yeah, X and Y should be of same length.`len(X)>len(Y)` in your case. I don't know what's your label comprised of. But if it's randomly generated data, then make your X data of same length as Y data.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I am trying this, if I get stuck somewhere, I will comment down. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah Sure. But try what I said above. First check if your label data is correct. Secondly, if it is some random generated data, then change `train_bow = bow[:split_num,:]` to `train_bow = bow[:len(train['label']),:]` inside `train_test_split()`.

Comment: Bro, I am done, succeeded, but the problem is now I have to shrink the train data to 65% instead of 80%. Is there a way to solve this? less training data means less accuracy, right?

Comment: Yeah. But you can't just add random values to the label data. It should have some meaning. What you want to achieve. That's why, I told you to check if your label data is correct.

Comment: yeah, I have checked my label data, it aligned according to each tweet. I know we can't just add random data in the label, but there is no way out then to make my train set 80% and do it?

Comment: Well, Thanks though, you made my day.

Answer (score 0):

if  can you comment out the f1_score and try, it should not give you that error. Let me know if it works, Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is in the line of train_test_split. Can you please help me regarding this?